# Deploy ASP.NET MVC application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have planned to develop a web application using MVC, can any one suggest me the how easy to deploy the application on the IIS?

And also let me know the steps to that.

regards,
Satish

Comment: If you want more accurate advice, you should maybe specify which version of IIS?  There is quite a big difference between deploying onto IIS6 vs IIS7.

Answer (score 2):

Just publish your application either to your server directory or locally and copy it to the the destination server.  Make sure your server is configured for MVC, see below:

[Using ASP.NET MVC with Different Versions of IIS](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs)

[Server installation options for ASP.NET MVC 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/07/13/server-installation-options-for-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

as rick says, and also, make sure (if IIS6) to use wildcard mapping - this needs to be added in the IIS control panel. again, our old friend google should throw up plenty of options on doing this. if you're under shared hosting, you can request it and most are happy to add it.

jim